# Passing structure as argument in C function

Tags: c

```
typedef struct { int b, p; } A;
void f(A c);
int main()
{
  int i;
  A a = {1,2};
  f(a);
  printf("%d,%d\n",a.b,a.p);
  return 0;
}
void f(A c)
{
  int j;
  c.b += 1;
  c.p += 2;
}
```

In the following code, why is it that a.b and a.p are still 1 and 2 even after being passed through f(a), which should change them to 2 and 3?

Comment: You passed the whole struct as an argument. The changes are then local to the function. You should pass a pointer, `void f(A *c)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are using is called call by value, in call by value the changes you are doing to function arguments will not be reflected in the caller, for that you need call by reference

```
typedef struct { int b, p; } A;

void f(A c);

void f2(A *c);

int main()
{
  int i;
  A a = {1,2};

  // call by value
  f(a);
  printf("%d,%d\n",a.b,a.p);

  //call by referecne    
  f2(&a);

  printf("%d,%d\n",a.b,a.p);
  return 0;
}

void f(A c)
{
  int j;
  c.b += 1;
  c.p += 2;
}

void f2(A *c)
{
  int j;
  c->b += 1;
  c->p += 2;
}
```